# page[size] getting updated from 10 to 1 when user lands on a page with only 1 result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari, active-model-serializers, json-api

```
#app/serializers/admin_serializer.rb
class AdminSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :access_locked?
end


#app/controllers/dashboard/admins_controller.rb
def index
    @search = Admin.search(params[:q])
    if params[:page]
      @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page][:number]).per(params[:page][:size])
    else
      @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(1).per(10)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @admins}
    end
end
```

On accessing `http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json` I am getting correct links, with `page[size]` param as 10. The subsequent page has only one admin object to show

```
"links": {
    "self": "http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "next": "http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=2&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "last": "http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=5&page%5Bsize%5D=10"
  }
```

But if I access the last link here i.e. `http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=5&page%5Bsize%5D=10`
The subsequent JSON cotains the following incorrect links, with `page[size]` param as 1. Since this page has only one admin object to show, all the other links thus generated contains `page[size]=1`

```
"links": {
    "self": "http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=5&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "first": "http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=10",
    "prev": "http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json?page%5Bnumber%5D=4&page%5Bsize%5D=10"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by replacing the 
`@admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page][:number]).per(params[:page][:size])` by `@admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page][:number]).per(10)`